# How to test Android app on all platforms

Tags: android

I had to accept a return on an Android app because the user told me it was not working on his Motorola Xoom. (The audio playback had some reverberation)

This is not a super high volume app, so I am not planning to go out and buy dozens of Androids to test it!

Also, it is an audio recorder app, so it does not work too well in an emulator.
How can I diagnose and correct the problem on the Xoom and in fact all other platforms, without investing a small fortune!

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do, if you're not averse to rooting, is installing different ROMs on your device. This will at least give you the chance to test on some different versions of Android and different UI skins (how many are available depends on your device).

I also read about services that test your app on different devices for you, but I'm not sure how much these cost.

Comment: Do you know where I would find a ROM for the XOOM, for example?

Comment: Oh, well you won't typically install ROMs for a different device, but you could look for a custom ROM for your device that matches the version installed on the Xoom (I think at this point it could be either Honeycomb or Ice Cream Sandwich). It won't help with every problem, but I've found that issues with different devices often come down to the Android version, especially if you've been unable to test on different Android versions up to this point.